# objective-c multiplication always equaling zero?

Tags: objective-c, multiplication

I have things object called - bombObject, which has a float property called 'blastRadius'.

When 'NSLog(@"%.2f",bombObject.blastRadius);' executes I get whatever i made it in the first pace e.g. 100 etc. But if execute: 'NSLog(@"%.2f",bombObject.blastRadius*(3/7));' I don't get 3/7 of the blastRadius, I get 0.00. However if i do 'NSLog(@"%.2f",(bombObject.blastRadius*3)/7);' I get the desired answer.

Why is this?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: In c and similar languages 3/7 = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An int/int will not promote to a float, so you end up with only an integer being returned.  3/7 is less than 1 so you end up truncating to 0.  You then multiply bombObject.blastRadius by 0 which gives you the 0.00 answer you are seeing.

Why does (bombObject.blastRadius*3)/7 work though?  Because bombObject.blastRadius*3 is a float resultant; a float / int would become a float which is why it works in this instance.

Comment: Thanks :). I have managed to never come across this before and felt really noobish for asking it. I guess bomb.blastRadius*(3.0/7) would have worked as well too then. :)

Answer (score 1):

(3/7) is evaluated as an integer expression resulting to zero, so blastRadius*(3/7) results to zero.

blastRadius*3 is evaluated as a float (float * int = float) , so the result is evaluated as a float value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You were perfectly right of course, but i gave the tick to Surrot, because his was better worded. Thanks for playing! :P

Comment: Glad you're taking care, so it's staying fun to help!